# Creating a Google Doc with MySQL to Make a Resume Template

Tags: gwt, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am interested in creating a way to query a database and then export that data to a Google Doc.  The Google Doc would have to be pre-formatted/formatted to the Industry standard.

The way I see it: each employee is the same (with some minor exceptions) based off their time in the job and their time in the position they are currently in.  With those criteria set, specialized options would then be available to annotate their specialized and/or additional duties.  All the job information and the specialized jobs are company-wide and able to be pre-formatted descriptions.  The data, based on the selected criteria is then output to Google Docs for revision and refinement.  The output would be a basic template of the employee’s time at the company, almost like a resume.

How should I go about it?  IS there already options built into Google Docs that allows this?